# Why can't I apply CSS3 Columns to this text?

Tags: css, tumblr, column-count

I'm trying to make my text have two columns on my tumbler blog. I made a class:

```
<style> 
.2col
{

    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 300px;
}
</style>
```

This works in a small test I made:

```
<div class="2col">
    Bunch of text
</div>
```

You can see it [here](http://inertreactants.tumblr.com/2col-test)

But when I try to apply this in my blog to just the text, it doesn't work. If I apply it to the entire blog, it works, but I want to only apply it to some text sections. Within tumblr, I am using:

```
<div class="2col">
    {Body}
</div>
```

However it doesn't change the text, which you see [here](http://inertreactants.tumblr.com/post/45281005422/test-post) on the main page of my blog (the lorem ipsum text). The {Body} part doesn't seem to have anything that should cause a problem (you can see the CSS and the text in the source for the page. I feel like I am missing some fundamental understanding about CSS classes, because I have not even been successful trying to add something simple to the text, like an underline. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

For reference, I posted an image to my blog of what I am trying to make, but I don't have enough reputation to add it here.

Comment: Because all your css column tags are browser prefixed eg. `-moz-column...` and `-wekkit-column...`. You are leaving Opera out. You might want to just add `column-...` as well ;)

Comment: I've added to `.2col div p: column-count: 2;` and it worked just fine on your blog.

Comment: Seems like it's fairly interpreter-dependent. I fixed it (on safari) by renaming it to "a2col". Now that it's working for me I will make it a bit more universal as expected. As for IE<10, it fails gracefully enough that I don't care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming your class - In most languages and naming conventions you shouldn't be starting with an integer.  Fairly sure this applies to CSS as well - it is likely that the interpreter is plainly ignoring it.

Comment: I think this may have fixed it! Odd that it works in the simple case but is ignored on the actual blog, but oh well.

Comment: @johnwalkr issues as a result of straying from standards are anyone's guess - the different browsers and vendors will handle the occurrence in their own way which is why you can't rely on them - best to stick to convention.  Your test-case may not have include the same (or any) `doctype`? which may also dictate events.  Glad you got it sorted though :)